# gradle subProject configuration dependencies not being add to war

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a main project that depends on 2 subProjects. All 3 projects have a custom configuration called server.

When I have the following war task, only the dependencies in the main project configuration.server are being added to the war.

```
task fatWar(type: War) {
    archiveName = "arms-fat.war"
    classpath configurations.server
    classpath configurations.compile
}
```

How do I add the subProject server configuration dependencies to the war?

EDIT:

Here are some snippets of my build files for context.

rootProject build.gradle

```
configurations {
    server
}
dependencies {
    server 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:2.22.2'
    ...
}
task fatWar(type: War) {
    archiveName = "arms-fat.war"
    classpath configurations.server
    classpath configurations.compile
}
```

subProject build.gradle

```
configurations {
    server
}
dependencies {
    server 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38'
    ...
}
```

When I run the fatWar task, the mysql-connector.jar, among others are not bundled in the war

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the subproject detail. I don't know how to solve this. Post a detailed question in the Gradle discussion forum.

Comment: Go over the comments in this posting: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-jar-all-class-output-from-all-sub-projects-into-one-jar/7049/2 .

Comment: thanks for the link. I was able to solve my problem with the subproject.each closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this (thanks to the link David provided) with the following:

```
subprojects.each { subproject -> evaluationDependsOn( subproject.path ) }

task fatWar(type: War) {
    archiveName = "arms-fims-fat.war"

    subprojects.each { subproject ->
        project.configurations.server.dependencies.addAll(subproject.configurations.server.dependencies)
    }

    classpath configurations.server
    classpath configurations.compile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, "classpath" is a property, not a method, so replace the two assignments with a single one, whose value is "configurations.server + configurations.compile".

Comment: the problem is that the subproject configurations.server (in separate build.gradle) aren't being added. Just the rootProject server and rootProject and subProjects compile configurations are added.

Comment: Yeah, I was confused.  I think my modified answer is more likely.

Comment: It is still missing the subProject configurations.server dependencies